# Solving surds without compairing

Tags: irrational-numbers

Question: Let $a + \sqrt{2b}  = 3 - 2\sqrt{2}$ .Find the value of $a - \sqrt{2b}$

What I did: I compared the whole numbers and the irrational numbers in both sides and calculated the answer $3 + 2\sqrt{2}$.

However, I am not very satisfied to do it this way. I could not manage to calculate it with the  algebraic formulas.

How to do it?

Comment: How to write 2^(1/2) as √2?

Comment: you have to writ \sqrt{2} in between dollars  to get $\sqrt{2}$

Comment: i do not understand why you do not want to compare those to get value of $a-\sqrt{2b}$.. I do not see any better way of doing this...

Comment: What kind of numbers are $a$ and $b$?

Comment: It is not mentioned what kind of numbers they are. I just wanted to know whether it can be done in any other way.

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ are real, it can't be done *anyway*. For example, $a=\pi$, $b=(3-2\sqrt2-\pi)^2/2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that $a$ and $b$ are integer (or rational), we have that
$$a-3=2\sqrt2-\sqrt{2b}=\sqrt2(2-\sqrt b)$$
or
$$\sqrt b=2-\frac{a-3}{\sqrt2}$$
Squaring,
$$b=4-2\sqrt2(a-3)+\frac{(a-3)^2}2$$
That is,
$$2\sqrt2(a-3)=4-b+\frac{(a-3)^2}2$$
R.H.S. is rational. Thus, $a-3=0$.